# C++ template function unused typename

Tags: c++, templates, forwarding-reference

I'm trying to get my head around C++ templates and copy semantics.
I understand why I can't call `assign1` (It asks for rvalue references and I'm providing an lvalue ref)
But then why am I able to call `assign2` which imposes the same constraints?

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
void assign1(Args&& ... arguments) { }

template<typename A, typename... Args>
void assign2(Args&& ... arguments) { }

template<typename A, typename B, typename... Args>
void assign3(Args&& ... arguments) { }

int main() {
    const int r = 2;
    assign1<int>(r);        // no matching function for call to...
    assign2<int>(r);        // ok!
    assign3<int>(r);        // no matching function for call to...
}
```

Comment: For `assign1`, you explicitly specify the parameter type, and the actual argument can't be converted to that type. For `assign2`, you explicitly specify `A`, but `A` isn't used for anything. Instead, `Args` is automatically deduced from the argument type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given `assign1<int>(r);`, you're specifying the template argument explicitly, then the parameter type of `assign1` would be `int&&`, as you said, it's rvalue-reference and can't be bound with lvalue.

Given `assign2<int>(r);`, you're specifying the 1st template argument `A` as `int`, the parameter pack `Args` will be deduced from the function argument `r`. Note that it's not rvalue-reference but [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references), which could accpet both lvalues and rvalues. (Depending on the function arguments are lvalues or rvalues, according to the type deduction result, the function parameter type would be lvalue-reference or rvalue-reference.)

Given `assign3<int>(r);`, you're specifying only the 1st template argument `A`, but the 2nd parameter parameter `B` can't be deduced from function argument and the calling fails.

---

If you want to make the function template accepting rvalues only, you can add `static_assert` like

```
template<typename A, typename... Args>
void assign2(Args&& ...) { 
    static_assert(((!std::is_lvalue_reference_v<Args>) && ...), "must be rvalue");
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3w2jx5J7jirJMMeh)

Or apply [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

```
template<typename A, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<((!std::is_lvalue_reference_v<Args>) && ...)> assign2(Args&& ...) {
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7Icf00IRlxDL3DTV)

Or add another overload taking lvalue-references and mark it as `delete`. (This approach works only when all the arguments are lvalues.)

```
template<typename A, typename... Args> 
void assign2(Args& ... arguments) = delete;
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bHXiVsgpn8qk8ndK)

Comment: I didn't understand this bit "Note that it's not rvalue-reference but forwarding reference". sorry I'm new to C++, I thought `&&` meant the function expects a r-value ref

Comment: @FRR When you declare it in the syntax as you showed in the code, it becomes forwarding reference; See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) for more informations.

Comment: Thanks! so this is some kind of "special" case. I find it a bit weird. What if I wanted to force my template function to only accept "r-value" reference only?

Comment: @FRR You can add `static_assert` or SFINAE to constrain the type to be rvalue-reference, or add a overload taking lvalue-reference and mark it as `delete`. e.g. `template<typename A, typename... Args> void assign2(Args& ... arguments) = delete;`.

Comment: Thanks! C++ sure is weird, what I get from this `&&` mean something slightly different when used in function/class `template`s. I'll keep that in mind as I get more familiar with the language. Thanks for your help!